# DbExecutionStrategy retrying more than MaxRetryCount

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i m using the DbExecutionStrategy to make my program support connection timeout when querying the server, but it is not working as expected.

Here is my class:

```
public class MyExecutionStrategy : DbExecutionStrategy
{
    static MyExecutionStrategy()
    {
        RetriesPerInstance = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    private const int MaxRetryCount = 5;
    private static TimeSpan _maxDelay = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);



    private int _instanceNo;

    public MyExecutionStrategy() : base(MaxRetryCount, _maxDelay)
    {
        _instanceNo = ++TotalInstances;
        RetriesPerInstance[_instanceNo] = 0;
    }

    public static Dictionary<int, int> RetriesPerInstance { get; private set; }

    public static int TotalRetries
    {
        get
        {
            return RetriesPerInstance.Values.Sum();
        }
    }

    public static int TotalInstances { get; private set; }

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception ex)
    {
        RetriesPerInstance[_instanceNo]++;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my query:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs xe)
    {
        var dengineEntities = new dengineEntities();

        try
        {
            var proj = dengineEntities.motorista_erro.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var tries = MyExecutionStrategy.TotalRetries;
        }
    }
```

For a single ToArray, it returns 42 Retries, and instantiates 14 Strategies before throwing the RetryLimitExceededException.

Why it does not stop at 5 attempts and why it creates more than one instance for a single query? is there something im not seeing?

[image]

these are my context classes:

```
public partial class dengineEntities : DbContext
{
    public dengineEntities()
        : base("name=dengineEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<motorista_erro> motorista_erro { get; set; }

}
public partial class motorista_erro
{
    public int MOT_ID { get; set; }
    public string MOT_NOME { get; set; }
    public bool MOT_SIT_FUNC_ID { get; set; }
    public int IDEMP { get; set; }
}
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="dengineEntities" ...etc...etc../>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you are getting the connection / using the ExecutionStrategy in your Form Controller?

Comment: updated Martin but im using entityframework, so the connection is created based on the dengineEntities connectionString... and for testing..im turning off my network to force "Unable to connect" mysqlexception

Comment: So where is the ExecutionStrategy wired in, sorry if I wasn't clear enough about wanting to know about that.

Comment: its my public class MyExecutionStrategy that a i posted above. i set it on my dbconfigurationclass.....public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", () => new MyExecutionStrategy());
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

It is stopping at 5 retries, look at the values in the RetriesPerInstance screenshot, each one has 6 or 0. The 6 retries means it retried 5 times and the 6th time it stopped.

So it sounds like your issue is somewhere else. How many times is the Form1_Load being called?

Comment: yeah 6 is correct, but the total instances that im not ok with it... Just Once